# Correctly positioning blurred background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "profile" type of page where the background of the header is a blurred version of the profile photo. I'm having trouble getting the overlay to work correctly.

I've got an example here: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/riwepifixe/edit?html,css,output)

The issue is that I can't get the background overlay to stop at the white border line. The '.bg img' element takes the height/width of the body element instead of the height/width 100% of the div.profile-header element. Why?

CSS:

```
.profile-header {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: #fff 1px solid;

  .bg {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;

    img {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
      -moz-filter: blur(15px);
      -o-filter: blur(15px);
      -ms-filter: blur(15px);
      filter: blur(15px);
    }
  }

  .profile-content {
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .profile-img {
    padding: 30px 5px;
    display: block;

    img {
      max-width: 150px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="profile-header">
    <div class="bg"> <img src="http://www.twoorist.com/resources/images/uploads/images/97714346f8b6a5c10d716643eee28a8e.jpg"></div>
    <div class="profile-content">
      <div class="profile-img">
        <img src="http://www.twoorist.com/resources/images/uploads/images/97714346f8b6a5c10d716643eee28a8e.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="header-content">
        <h2>John Doe</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Some content down here.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not clear what this is supposed to look like but your positioning is a weird mixture.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, thanks for taking a look. This is the closest thing I could find with a google search. I want the background of the header to be a blurred version of the profile photo. See something similar [here](https://epic-pxls.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/fe3846b4-53c7-4921-b7cb-e663b68293dc.jpg)

Comment: Hmm...you may have to rejig the structure to do that. I'd have to think.

Comment: How can i save changes in jsbin?

Comment: Do you need specific requirement like IE9+ ?

Comment: @NenadVracar cmd-s if you're on a Mac or File>Save Snapshot from the jsbin menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tidied up the positioning a little, not using `position:fixed` helps here but the main trick was using `overflow` hidden on the parent.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Bjoezy)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.profile-header {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(50deg);
  filter: blur(5px) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(50deg);
}
.profile-img img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-header">

  <div class="bg">
    <img src="http://www.twoorist.com/resources/images/uploads/images/97714346f8b6a5c10d716643eee28a8e.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="profile-content">

    <div class="profile-img">
      <img src="http://www.twoorist.com/resources/images/uploads/images/97714346f8b6a5c10d716643eee28a8e.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="header-content">
      <h2>John Doe</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get most of the way there by cleaning up your `position` attributes.

```
.profile-header {
    position: relative;
}
.profile-header .bg {
    position: absolute;

    /* this will crop the blurry edge to contain it perfectly above the white line */
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

The position of the `.bg` div will now be set relative to the position of the `.profile-header` div (which is as tall as the content that it contains), unlike before where it was set relative to the position of the page (which is as tall as all of the content on the page).

You can see an example of this here:

http://jsbin.com/sajazoyiva/1/edit?html,css,output

[image: The header is cleaned up by altering the position of the css]